# Why is Entity FrameworkCore not being recognised when it has been added to the executable Path

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core, entity-framework-core

After installing and adding dotnet ef to vs code I entered this command in the terminal.

> dotnet ef migrations add Initial

Then I got this output:

> Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found. Possible reasons for this include:   * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.   * You intended to execute a .NET program, but dotnet-ef does not exist.   * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.

I've verified that dotnet ef has been added to the executable path.

I've tried re-installing, and everything else.

It simply will not recognize dotnet ef.